# Summary of C# naming conventions (official Microsoft conventions)

Tags: naming, naming-standards, coding-style

I am struggling with naming convetions in C# I do not know when to use PascalCase or camelCase. I have read Microsoft's naming convention, but I got lost ther http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx

As far as I know this is correct:

```
public int Number;
private int number;
public void Method();
private void method();
int number;//for any local variable
```

But in context of that above how should I name components in XAML: `x:Name="Button"` or `x:Name="button"`. They seems to be private field so I should use camelCase, but on the other hand everywhere on the examples I see PascalCase for `x:Name`

I do not ask about one's habits, but orthodoxic/official/C# guru style.

Comment: @Carson63000 In this link there is lot of talking, no examples.

Comment: Lower case private methods are **not** part of official Microsoft naming convention. Personally I have never seen a C# project that use such casing. I'm not saying noone ever does, but it's kind of exotic and not recommmended by MS.

Comment: The framework conventions only apply to externally visible types/members (visibility is `public` or `protected`). For the rest you can use project/company specific conventions.

Answer (score 15):

The conventions I use are

```
//non-private variable
variableName

//private variable
_variableName

//methods
MethodName

//parameters
parameterName

//Properties
PropertyName
```

These are standard MS c# conventions. [There is a list here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
If you want something to help you keep nice clean code following conventions, consider [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) add-on for Visual Studio

Comment: The underscore as the (private) field prefix is a controversial one. Personally I use it, but it has a suspicious taste to me and I don't follow this convention in all projects.

Comment: Yeah, it does seem like a controversial subject. It is [discussed briefly on MSDN.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/044a1246-0a15-48d5-902c-9c6c462af8b2/when-to-prefix-a-variable-with-underscore?forum=csharpgeneral) It appears the convention originated in c/c++

Answer (score 4):

I read the MS standards, a long time ago. All I remember and use is:

- UpperCamelCase for public methods and properties
- lowerCamelCase for protected/private methods and properties, also parameters

At the time, there was no XAML, but I don't expect precise consistency across languages.

In the end, **no one's standards matter but your own**. Or your team's. Or your boss's. But mostly your own.

Comment: I would mostly agree with this answer, with the caveat that anything public should follow the idioms and conventions of the language. Since a C# developer is going to expect to find VerbNoun methods (like `ToString()` or `ExecuteNonQuery()`), you should both name and capitalize your methods to meet their expectations.

Comment: Lower case for private methods?? Not in their official guidelines http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx it isn't. I have also never seen such convention in open-source projects maintained by Microsoft (like ASP MVC or Entity Framework).

Comment: @KonradMorawski: I haven't read the conventions in about a decade, thanks for the update.

Comment: Isn't "UpperCamelCase" better known as PascalCase?

Comment: @CraigW: "better known" is subjective ;)

Comment: @StevenA.Lowe I [disagree](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?word1=PascalCase&word2=UpperCamelCase). ;-)

Comment: @CraigW: bwahahahahaha! awesome!

Comment: "no one's standards matter but your own"  That's what I will tell my team the next time they ask me why I write everything in CAPS.